# Need help in calling scrollspy refresh in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

bootstrap scroll spy docs say:

> When using scrollspy in conjunction with adding or removing of elements from the DOM, you'll need to call the refresh method like so:

```
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
 var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
 })
```

and I want to implement this here(http://mixitup.io/#Documentation):

```
$('#Grid').mixitup({
targetSelector: '.mix',
onMixLoad: null,
onMixStart: null,
onMixEnd: null
});
```

How to do that?

---

Answer by abhidev is exactly what's required, it's my question which was incomplete.

So anyone having same problem, here is the solution(just replaced 'this' with 'body':

```
$('#grid').mixitup({
onMixEnd: function(){
    console.log('Mixit end called');
    $('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
        var $spy = $('body').scrollspy('refresh')
    });
    console.log
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try calling the scrollspy(refresh) on the onMixEnd cllback of the mixit.

```
$('#Grid').mixitup({
    targetSelector: '.mix',
    onMixLoad: null,
    onMixStart: null,
    onMixEnd: function(){
        console.log('Mixit end called');
        $('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
            var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
        });
        console.log
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Abhi for  your response.
May be my logic is wrong, but it didn't do  the   trick for me.

Comment: The actual scenario that I am creating a bootstrap project and using the scrollspy feature, it works all fine untill I hook the mixitup function. 

After intializing mixitup, the scrollspy starts to behave abnormal.
All sections above the section which is using mixitup work fine, but below they all are getting detected wrong.